# Python: Change the script's working directory to a different directory to read constants

Tags: python, directory, constants

My script is trying to read my utils from a different folder. I keep getting Import Error. PFB my script :

```
import sys
import os

abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname+"/../../dags/golden/")
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
sys.path.append(dname)

import utils
semantics_config = utils.get_config()
```

And my folder structure is as follows :

- /home/scripts/golden/script.py
- /home/dags/golden/utils.py

Output is :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check.py", line 22, in 
    import utils
ImportError: No module named utils

Any pointers will be greatly helpful!

Comment: You should show the complete output your script produces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import sys
import os

abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname+"/../../dags/golden/")
dname = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(dname)

import utils
semantics_config = utils.get_config()
```

You are again assigning "dname" as old path.
So use `os.getcwd()`

or

```
import sys
import os

abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
sys.path.append(dname+"/../../dags/golden/")

import utils
semantics_config = utils.get_config()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in your script.

os.chdir(dname+"/../../dags/golden/"), only changes your current working directory, but not change the value of variable "abspath"

So the value of "dname" keep the same before and after your "os.chdir"

just do sys.path.append(dname+"/../../dags/golden/"), you will get what you want.

BTW, python is very easy to locating the problem and learn. Maybe, You just need to add a print before you using a variable. And, don't forge to remove those print before you release your scripts.